# puzzel on DOM based XSS

Tags: xss

I have a page scanned by IBM AppScan, it reports 2 potential DOM based XSS issues. But after a long time analysis and Google search I could not figure out what's the risk of the code. Could you help me to identify the issue?

1. `window.location = window.location.href + '&a=b'` //compose a new url and redirect
2. `var width = $(window).width();` //$ is jQuery

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery framework is prone to DOM-based XSS because many jQuery functions/methods actually interpret JavaScript passed in a string. Your code on line 2 could be vulnerable to XSS if "window" were a string. If window is not a string, this should be safe.

Your code on line 1 reads window.location.href which could contain injected JS code. This possibly tainted data could lead to XSS if it were interpreted or added to the DOM, which does not appear to be the case here.